# Ruby on Rails: Product categorization & display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a product page and 4 different category tabs. A created product can only belong to one of the 4 categories/tabs on the page. How could I choose the category the product belongs to via a form & How can I load the products belonging to each category?

My current setup for loading created products onto the page is this.

This is an example of ONLY ONE tab Category selection link...

```
<a href="#samplePacks" aria-controls="samplePacks" data-toggle="tab">
  <h2 class="base-text">Samples</h2>
  <%= image_tag("btn_Category_1.png", :alt => "Category one", class: "image-pad center") %>
</a>
```

Followed by its corresponding tab, linked to the selector above...

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="samplePacks">
  <div class="wellone pack-well">
    <div class="row" id="samplePillars">

      <% @packs.each do |pack| %>
        <div class="col-md-4 pack-pad">
          <%= link_to pack_path(pack) do %>
            <%= image_tag("#{pack.art_link}", :alt => "Product Image", :width => 333, :height => 333, class: "feat-img") %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you click on any of the 4 tabs, you arrive at its unique category of items. There is no "display all items regardless of the category" each item cannot move from its category.

What is the code I need to add to the `<% @packs.each do |pack| %>` to load specific categories?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You mean via a "form" not a "forum"? And you have a couple of fundamental questions here regarding how to handle rails associations in forms. Have you looked at the Rails tutorials on this? Do a Google search on "rails handling associations in forms" and read up. You'll find a lot of good information there.

Comment: Yes, I meant a form. Thank you for the proper query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should have `category_id` in `products` table and then you need to setup the associations in `Product` and `Category` Model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

and in `Category` Model

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end
```

Now, in `products/new.html.erb`,

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :category_id %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name,prompt: "Select Category" %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And then you can make use of the association to show the products of each category with `@category.products`. Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you for this! What is the .erb code needed to load a single category? Each tab doesn't have any more primary categories in them, so clicking on the tab will load its ONE category. I've updated the question, you might have a better understanding of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: If you have `@categories = Category.all` in your action, inside your tabpanel you can have iterate over `@categories.where('name = ?', 'Your Category Name')`

Comment: Now does this `@categories = Category.all` go into the category controller or the product controller?

Comment: In any controller action where you want the tab functionality to work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having a hard time figuring out where to place this `@categories.where` code snippet. I'm not a ruby pro by any means.

Comment: Can what all `controllers` and `models` you have now ? also exactly in which page you are trying to display the tabs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163053/discussion-between-jake-and-anees-muhammed).

Answer (score 1):

For what you are looking for you can use the `collection_select`.

```
collection_select(:product, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :category_name, prompt: true)
```

This is a good approach as it will load all dropdown options dynamically from your database.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

Comment: My page uses 4 tabs each loading their own category. This answer does, however, meet the needs of one of my tabs with a category system for its products. Would you have a solution for the tab categories?

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble visualizing this. Can you add a screenshot of your application showcasing these 'tabs'?

Comment: I've included the code I use for one of the 4 tabs, let me know if you need me to add another one to reference, thanks!

Comment: So each tab has a different category in it? I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, each tab has only one category of items. Only one of the 4 tabs has multiple dropdown sub-categories (I think your first answer will solve this). I want to make sure each item can only belong to one of the 4 tabs. I figured if I made 4 completely different models for each category it would conflict with making orders/shopping carts.

Comment: I've updated the question at the bottom, sorry for causing so much hassle on this and thank you so much for sticking around to help me, I mean it!